# R: how to paste0() backslash?

Tags: r, paste, slash

I need to output windows directory, however for `paste0()` I can only use "\", for example `paste0("C:\\AB\\", "CD")` where the output is `"C:\\AB\\CD"`.

How to convert this to `"C:\AB\CD"`?

Comment: It is what you want. Check `cat(paste0("C:\\AB\\", "CD"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using `cat()`

```
cat("C:\\AB\\CD")
> C:\AB\CD
```

Answer (score 0):

The string output from paste0() is already in your desired format.
The cat() command shows this as Negrito recommended.